# Godot "Object was deleted while awaiting a callback" with failed method _update_callback

Tags: godot

I'm getting the following error, and I can't seem to reproduce it reliably

```
Failed method: MarginContainer:_update_callback target ID: 43636
Object was deleted while awaiting a callback
Object was deleted while awaiting a callback
Object was deleted while awaiting a callback
Object was deleted while awaiting a callback
Object was deleted while awaiting a callback
Object was deleted while awaiting a callback
Object was deleted while awaiting a callback
Object was deleted while awaiting a callback
Object was deleted while awaiting a callback
Object was deleted while awaiting a callback
Object was deleted while awaiting a callback
Object was deleted while awaiting a callback
Object was deleted while awaiting a callback
Object was deleted while awaiting a callback
Object was deleted while awaiting a callback
Object was deleted while awaiting a callback
...
TOTAL BYTES: 4194288
NULL count: 185
CALL : 174575
CALL _update_callback: 2
ERROR: Message queue out of memory. Try increasing 'memory/limits/message_queue/max_size_kb' in project settings.
```

I've also found [this post](https://godotforums.org/d/31530-error-message-queue-out-of-memory-in-a-for-loop) on the Godot Forums talking about CanvasItems updating too quickly, however I've disabled all my calls to `Update()`, yet the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the `call_deferred` method on some of my UI code fixed the issue. Maybe it has something to do with attempting to reparent a child too many times within the same frame.